# Erro na inicialização do glassfish no eclipse - asadmin path not found, bootstrap e sem domain

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, servidor

Depois de muita procura sem resposta, venho aqui solicitar ajuda.
Utilizo Eclipse Kepler e glashfish 3.1. O que acontece é que quando vou iniciar o servidor do glassfish, normalmente ou por debug, o servidor retorna o erro "Launch process failed with exit code 1".

Log do servidor:

```
    Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9009
    Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
    ERROR: Error parsing system bundle export statement: org.osgi.framework;         version=1.6.0, org.osgi.framework.launch; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.wiring;         version=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.startlevel; version=1.0.0,         org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver;         version=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.hooks.service; version=1.1.0,         org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.service.packageadmin;         version=1.2.0, org.osgi.service.startlevel; version=1.1.0, org.osgi.service.url;         version=1.0.0, org.osgi.util.tracker; version=1.5.0, ,         org.glassfish.embeddable;org.glassfish.embeddable.spi;version=3.1.1         (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length.)
    org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length.
        at         org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.normalizeExportClauses(Manife        stParser.java:729)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.<init>        (ManifestParser.java:191)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.<init>        (ExtensionManager.java:220)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.<init>(Felix.java:374)
        at         org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkFactory.newFramework(FrameworkFactory.java:28)
        at         com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher.launchOSGiFrameWork(OSGiF        rameworkLauncher.java:77)
        at         com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFish        RuntimeBuilder.java:128)
        at         org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
        at         org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
        at         com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112        )
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at                 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at         sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at         com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
    mai 27, 2014 1:26:08 PM BundleProvisioner install
    ADVERT�NCIA: Failed to install         file:/C:/Users/Luccas/Documents/Servidor/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/flashlight-extra-jdk-        packages.jar
    org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2785)
        at         org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:165)
        at         com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install(BundleProvisioner.jav        a:446)
        at         com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.installBundles(BundleProvisio        ner.java:208)
        at         com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFish        RuntimeBuilder.java:139)
        at         org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
        at         org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
        at         com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112        )
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at         sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at         sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at         com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
    Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:638)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:414)
        at         org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.addExtensionBundle(ExtensionManager.java:401)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:2751)
        ... 13 more
```

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda

Edit:

Parece que quando o glassfish foi instalado o domain não havia sido criado. 
Como solucionar o problema (inglês) - https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16155

Então começou a acusar que faltava o boostrap, erro simples, conferir o Server Runtime
Maiores informações e como resolver (também em inglês) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838554/glassfish3-cant-start-cause-bootstrap-jar-not-found

Comment: Luccas, por acaso você está usando o JDK 8? Se sim tente uma versão mais antiga.

Comment: Tentei e não tive sucesso. Tentei recolocar o servidor e com as mudanças de jdk e nada.

Comment: Subindo pelo `asadmin` o GlassFish inicializa?

Comment: Ao que parece o `asadmin` diz "O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado" quando tento abri-lo. Poderia ser algo no próprio glassfish então?

Comment: @LuccasS Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

O AP resolveu a questão:

[O problema](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16155).

[A solução](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16838554/221800).

Verifique a pasta onde o  Glassfish é o mesmo configurado no Eclipse.

> Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments